# Decoding A Json String in php

Tags: php, json

I want to know how i can acess this decoded Json and this is my code

```
 <?php

    $jsonObject = $_GET["UserDetails"];

    ?>

Where jsonObject = {\"Email\":\"joissumanh@gmail.com\"}
```

How can i decode this above Json and acess it. Looking forward for a indepth Answer. ThankYou

Comment: `json_decode($arr, true);`

Comment: i know that!! i want to know how to access the property?? can you please answer how?

Comment: The answer he give is was not clear

Comment: @Jois https://eval.in/531511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the object property by using the `->`

```
<?php
    $jsonObject = json_decode($_GET["UserDetails"]);
    echo $jsonObject->Email; // will print joissumanh@gmail.com
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you use `json_decode()` function, then the assigned variable becomes PHP stdClass, which can be access as below.

```
<?php

$jsonAsString = '{"Email": "username@domainname.tld"}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonAsString);

// Now $jsonObj is a stdClass Object which can be accessed as below

echo $jsonObj -> Email;

?>
```

Clickhere to see sample http://ideone.com/E28wUS